# discord.py: Run a command on start-up

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command that checks some scheduled events and then updates some channels.
I would like for this command to run upon start-up, but I cannot invoke the command without access to a context object.

Both ctx.invoke(command) and bot.get_cog("Command").command(ctx) need some context object.
Creating my own context seems not possible as I don't have access to a Message object.

It seems like this should be pretty basic behavior, but I cannot figure it out.

EDIT:
I need to be able to call this "something" command upon startup, it uses a context object to get all the channels of the guild, so I would need to create/get a context object or somehow find all the channels of the current guild I'm in some other way.

```py
@commands.command(name=something)
async def something(ctx):
  channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="some_name")
  await channel.send("something")
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your code?

Comment: how about `@bot.event` `def on_ready()` ? maybe better show minimal working code with your problem - so we could run it and test ideas.

Comment: Updated with small sample code

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate coroutine that can be called from both the command and other parts of your code.  So instead of

```
@bot.command()
async def my_command(ctx):
    ...

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await ctx.invoke(my_command) # doesn't work
```

You can do

```
async def do_stuff():
    ...

@bot.command()
async def my_command(ctx):
    await do_stuff()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await do_stuff()
```

Comment: I was not clear enough in my description, the command in question that updates some channels uses the context object to get the guild's channels like
```ctx.guild.channels```
So I need to either the the channels without the context object or somehow create/get a context object some other way

Comment: What do you know about the guild(s) you want when you're starting your bot?  You coroutine can take arguments like any other function.